# Multiple IF statements and concatenation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

[image: Excel example]

So far I've managed to concatenate cells I1 and J1 with the words "From" and "To" and put them on separate lines using:

```
=CONCATENATE("From: ",I1," ","To: ",J1)
```

I've also managed to populate column L (only if there is data in column H) using this:

```
=IF(H1="","","Notes: " & H1)
```

Now, I'd like to populate column M with these two formulas combined, but I'm lost in a maze of IF statements which don't work:

```
=IF(H1="","","Notes: " & H1,"",if(I1="","","From: " & I1," ",if(J1="","","From: " & J1)))
```

Comment: =IF(H1="","Notes: " & H1,CONCATENATE("From: ",I1," ","To: ",J1))

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The poster has shown what they've tried, and shown a screen shot. The question is also clear... +1

Answer (score 5):

Concatenate() is not required to concatenate text. The & sign does the same thing and is much less typing. Consider

```
="From: "&I1&" "&"To: "&J1&" "&IF(H1="","","Notes: " & H1)
```

Comment: This is a small and sweet answer

Answer (score 2):

Add the IF statement as another argument for CONCATENATE

EG:

```
=CONCATENATE("From: ",I1," ","To: ",J1," ", IF(H1="","","Notes: " & H1))
```

That said, I don't know if you really intended to reproduce the same information again. You could just do:

```
=K1&L1
```

As you've already made K1 and L1 as expected, this would just put the two together.